# Smaller font size in quote environment relative to context

Tags: footnotes, conditionals, fontsize, quoting

I want to have all quotes in the `quote`-environment in a smaller font. This is possible with the [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)-package and the command:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\small}
```

But if I use a quote-environment in a footnote, the quotation is set to fontsize 'small' and therefore larger than the footnote-size. In the footnote I would like it better to have the same size as the footnote-text.

Is it possible to redefine the `quote`-environment relative to the context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be better to stick to a scaled version of the quote, regardless of the location of use (body text or footnote). In that regard, you were two letters and a package too short:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{relsize,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller}% Step font down one size relative to current font.
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\begin{quote}
This is a quote.
\end{quote}
Here is some more text\footnote{Some text.
\begin{quote}
This is a quote in a footnote.
\end{quote}
Some more text.}
\end{document}
```

[`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) uses `\smaller` to step the font down one size from the current font size. For scalable fonts at any size, also include [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm).

---

Alternatively, conditional scaling is also possible for `quote`. The following assumes you're using a default document class (like `article`, `book` or `report`) or one that doesn't alter the footnote printing mechanise `\@makefntext`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newif\if@in@footnote@
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent\@in@footnote@true
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\if@in@footnote@\else\small\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\begin{quote}
This is a quote.
\end{quote}
Here is some more text\footnote{Some text.
\begin{quote}
This is a quote in a footnote.
\end{quote}
Some more text.}
\end{document}
```

`\if@in@footnote@` is set to true inside when creating the footnote, which is picked up inside the `quote` environment. If true, then no font change occurs, otherwise it uses `\small`.

---

Under the [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes, you could use

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@in@footnote@
\renewcommand{\@footnotetext}[1]{%
  \scr@saved@footnotetext{\@in@footnote@true #1}%
  \csname FN@mf@prepare\endcsname
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\if@in@footnote@\else\small\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I already tried the relsize-package, but for me it gives an even smaller font size. So the other approach is right for me and almost the solution. Unfortunately it clashes with a footnote redefinition. I use the scrreprt-class and the following redefinition:</br>>\deffootnote[2em]{2em}{1em}{\makebox[2em][r]{\bfseries\thefootnotemark}\enskip}</br>> 
\setlength{\footnotesep}{.85\baselineskip}</br>>
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{} Any idea?

Comment: @peregrinustyss: Try the KOMA-script suggestion at the bottom of the post (I just added it).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. – BTW, isn't it possible to edit a comment? Because I messed with my previous one and now there are strange characters …

Comment: @peregrinustyss: You have 5 minutes to edit a comment... However, since the problem has been dealt with for KOMA-script, the comment(s) are actually obsolete. So we can delete them...

Comment: @Werner I noticed that there seems to be a problem with the first suggestion. For some reason it messes up the line spacing in the paragraph just before the quote. You can see this if you add two paragraph stretching over more than one line before the quote and compare them. I managed to get around this by adding a `\par` just in front of the `\smaller`. Not sure whether that is the correct way to do it.