# Quote Text Size Doesn't Change using the Quoting package

Tags: fontsize, quoting

I have a large `book` template. The book contains quotes, for which I use the `quoting` package.

In the book, the font size of the quote's text has the same size as the book's normal text, which is a mistake: it should be `small`, per my code in the `quoting` entry in my `PREAMBLE`. When I try to actually make it `small`, the quote's text becomes larger than the surrounding text.

What follows is the faulty code.
At one point, in trying pinpoint the faulty portion of the code, I removed all the code located between % FRONTMATTER STARTS % and % MAINMATTER STARTS % and, boom, the quoted text became `small`, as intended. I have no idea why though. Is there a conflict with some of the TOC related code I'm using?

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading

\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For links color
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{colortbl} % To define colors
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone
\setsansfont{Cabin}

% QUOTE TEXT MARGINS + FONT SIZE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[font=small,rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}

% FOOTNOTES IN QUOTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage[
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=teal,
urlcolor=teal
]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

% CHAPTER, SECTION, SUBSECTION STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Cabin}

\begin{document}

    % FRONTMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \frontmatter
    {
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\textbf{}
        \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % This line removes dots for Sections and under
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \clearpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
    \small{\listoftables}
    \clearpage

    % MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \mainmatter

Call me Ishmael. Some years ago- never mind how long precisely- having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off- then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. This is my substitute for pistol and ball.

\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=\parindent]
    Shakespeare wrote Moby-Dick, using Melville as a Ouija board.
    \attrib{Ray Bradbury }
\end{quoting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I put in `SMALL` in both the book and my test code, which is you above, nothing changed in either instance. I went back to `small` in the test code and the quote went back to `small`, as before.

Comment: Your comment about the `etoolbox` package is intriguing. Going to look into it. It may be messing things up. But then, the code in the main book and the code in the test file are the same ... so, if `etoolbox` was a problem, it would be a problem in both, no?

Comment: you need to provide an example that shows the problem. It is always possible to do this, do not try to make a small example from an empty document, start from a copy of your document and delete any text you can delete while still showing the problem, then delete any package not used by the remaining text, so you end up with a small example you can post here.

Comment: Added the faulty code after much trimming. Thanks of the suggestion, David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, here: [Smaller font size in quote environment relative to context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96498/smaller-font-size-in-quote-environment-relative-to-context)

**Added:** `\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}`

**Qualified the `quoting` environment:** `\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}`

**Plus:** `\AtBeginEnvironment{quoting}{\smaller}`

And the quote is now small and extends all the way to the right margin of my two column document.

**Here's the code:**

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palladio needs more leading

\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For links color
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{colortbl} % To define colors
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone
\setsansfont{Cabin}

% QUOTE TEXT MARGINS + FONT SIZE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtBeginEnvironment{quoting}{\smaller}


% FOOTNOTES IN QUOTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage[
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=teal,
urlcolor=teal
]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

% CHAPTER, SECTION, SUBSECTION STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Cabin}

\begin{document}

    % FRONTMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \frontmatter
    {
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}\textbf{}
        \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % This line removes dots for Sections and under
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \clearpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
    \small{\listoftables}
    \clearpage

    % MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \mainmatter

    Call me Ishmael. Some years ago- never mind how long precisely- having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off- then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. This is my substitute for pistol and ball.

    \begin{quoting}
        Call me Ishmael. Some years ago- never mind how long precisely- having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. 
        \attrib{Ishmael}
    \end{quoting}

\end{document}
```